# Json.NET convert linq result into IEnumerable<JObject>

Tags: json, linq, json.net

I have a LINQ object that needs to be converted into IEnumerable JObject 
The following JavaScriptSerializer is working fine in that I can see the json data from the LINQ object.

```
Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(results)
```

I need to do something similar with the JSON.NET but I have tried...

```
Dim jobject = New JObject(results)    
Dim jarray = New JArray(results)
```

both have the following error. "Could not determine JSON object type for type Services.Models.Log"
I have tried this

```
Dim jobject = JObject.FromObject(results)
```

with the following error. "Object serialized to Array. JObject instance expected."

The only code that seems to work is this.

```
Dim jtoken = JToken.FromObject(results)
```

but how to I turn the JToken back into a JObject so that I can return it as IEnumerable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this way :

```
Dim jobjects As IEnumerable(Of JObject) = 
        results.Select(Function(x) JObject.FromObject(x))
```